# How can i use a list of properties with razor to complete the crud

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, crud

I'm working on a project with .NET framework and asp.net, it's a web application that can handle certain forms for an insurance company.
The concept is to fill the forms in order to complete the registration.

For that i have created 5 classes, each class has certain properties as following :

class 1 :

```
public class BulletinAdhesionRMA
{
    [Key]
    public int BulletinId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Type de bulletin")]
    public TypeBulletinEnum TypeBulletin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "N° d'adhésion")]
    public string NumeroAdhesion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Employeur Employeur { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Nom de jeune fille (Si affilié de sexe féminin)")]
    public string NomJeuneFille { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Sexe Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Situation de famille")]
    public SituationFamille SituationFamiliale { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date de naissance")]
    public DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Type de document d'identification (Cin, passeport, etc...)")]
    public TypeDocumentIdentification TypeDocument { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "N° document")]
    public string NumeroDocument { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Adresse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Ville { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Pays { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Téléphone")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date d'affiliation")]
    public DateTime DateAffiliation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date d'entrée en fonction")]
    public DateTime DateEntreeFonction { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Catégorie du personnel")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CategoriePersonnel { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Emploi { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Matricule { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Salaire annuel (ou capital)")]
    public double SalaireAnnuel { get; set; }

    public List<BeneficiaireConjoint> BeneficiareConjoints { get; set; }

    public List<BeneficiaireEnfant> BeneficiareEnfants { get; set; }

    public List<BeneficiaireEnCasDeces> BeneficiareEnCasDeces { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Le :")]
    public DateTime FaitLe { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    [Display(Name = "Fait à")]
    public string FaitA { get; set; }


}
```

class 2 :

```
public class Employeur
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("BulletinAdhesionRMA")]
    public int EmployeurId { get; set; }
    public BulletinAdhesionRMA BulletinAdhesionRMA { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "N° Client")]
    public string NumeroClient { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "N° Filiale")]
    public string NumeroFiliale { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Raison Social")]
    public string RaisonSocial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "N° Contrat")]
    public string NumeroContrat { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
}
```

class 3 :

```
public class BeneficiaireConjoint
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? BulletinId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BulletinId")]
    public BulletinAdhesionRMA BulletinAdhesionRMA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }


    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }


    public Sexe? Genre { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date de naissance")]
    public DateTime? DateNaissance { get; set; }
}
```

class 4 :

```
public class BeneficiaireEnfant
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? BulletinId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BulletinId")]
    public BulletinAdhesionRMA BulletinAdhesionRMA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }


    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }


    public Sexe? Genre { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date de naissance")]
    public DateTime? DateNaissance { get; set; }
}
```

class 5 :

```
public class BeneficiaireEnCasDeces
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? BulletinId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BulletinId")]
    public BulletinAdhesionRMA BulletinAdhesionRMA { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }


    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }


    public Sexe? Genre { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date de naissance")]
    public DateTime? DateNaissance { get; set; }
}
```

After that, i have created the "DbContext" in order to create the database structure :

```
public class BulletinAdhesionDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BulletinAdhesionDbContext() : base("BulletinAdhesionConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BulletinAdhesionDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public DbSet<BulletinAdhesionRMA> BulletinAdhesionsRMA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employeur> Employeurs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BeneficiaireConjoint> BeneficiaireConjoints { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BeneficiaireEnfant> BeneficiaireEnfants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BeneficiaireEnCasDeces> BeneficiaireEnCasDeces { get; set; }
}
```

Also, i'm gonna need a "controller" to make things as they're supposed to be :

```
public class BulletinAdhesionRMAController : Controller
{
    public BulletinAdhesionDbContext db = new BulletinAdhesionDbContext();
    // GET: BulletinAdhesionRMA
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "" )] BulletinAdhesionRMA bulletinAdhesionRMA)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.BulletinAdhesionsRMA.Add(bulletinAdhesionRMA);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();

    }
}
```

And finally the view responsible for the form filling :

```
@model BulletinAdhesion.Models.BulletinAdhesionRMA
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BulletinAdhesionRMA", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row" id="rma" >
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/logos/rma.png" width="50" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="m-b-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeBulletin)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TypeBulletin, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeBulletin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.NumeroAdhesion)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.NumeroAdhesion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroAdhesion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-header custom-card-header">
            <h4>Employeur : </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroClient)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroClient, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employeur.NumeroClient, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroContrat)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroContrat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employeur.NumeroContrat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroFiliale)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Employeur.NumeroFiliale, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employeur.NumeroFiliale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Employeur.RaisonSocial)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Employeur.RaisonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employeur.RaisonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Employeur.Adresse)
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Employeur.Adresse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employeur.Adresse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header custom-card-header">
            <h4>Adhérent : </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nom)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prenom)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomJeuneFille)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomJeuneFille, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomJeuneFille, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateNaissance)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateNaissance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateNaissance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SituationFamiliale)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SituationFamiliale, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SituationFamiliale, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeDocument)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TypeDocument, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeDocument, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocument)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocument, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocument, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adresse)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adresse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adresse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ville)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ville, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ville, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pays)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pays, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pays, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateAffiliation)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateAffiliation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateAffiliation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateEntreeFonction)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateEntreeFonction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateEntreeFonction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriePersonnel)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoriePersonnel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriePersonnel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emploi)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Emploi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emploi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Matricule)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Matricule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Matricule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalaireAnnuel)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalaireAnnuel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalaireAnnuel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header custom-card-header">
            <h4>Bénéficiaire (s) Prestations maladie : </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:25px !important;">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Nom (jeune fille)</th>
                            <th>Prénom</th>
                            <th>Sexe</th>
                            <th>Date de naissance</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @*<tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>CO1</td>

                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Genre, new { @class = "form-control" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].DateNaissance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[0].DateNaissance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>CO2</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].DateNaissance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareConjoints[1].DateNaissance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Prénom</th>
                                <th>Sexe</th>
                                <th>Date de naissance</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>EO @i</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].Prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].Prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].DateNaissance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnfants[i - 1].DateNaissance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>*@
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header custom-card-header">
            <h4>Bénéficiaire (s) en cas de décès : </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @*@for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnCas[i].Prenom)
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnCas[i].Prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeneficiareEnCas[i].Prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                }*@

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaitA)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaitA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaitA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaitLe)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaitLe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaitLe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
}
```

As you can see in the "controller", i'm only saving the data of the simple properties, but if you notice in the view there is a comment table, that table contains a list of "BeneficiaireConjoint" and "BeneficiaireEnfant", the two properties are properties of "BulletinAdhesionRMA" but they are types of List.

So far so  good, but when i try this code in my controller it doesn't work.

```
public class BulletinAdhesionRMAController : Controller
{
    public BulletinAdhesionDbContext db = new BulletinAdhesionDbContext();
    // GET: BulletinAdhesionRMA
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "" )] BulletinAdhesionRMA bulletinAdhesionRMA)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.BulletinAdhesionsRMA.Add(bulletinAdhesionRMA);
            db.BeneficiaireConjoints.Add(bulletinAdhesionRMA.BeneficiareConjoints);
            db.BeneficiaireEnfants.Add(bulletinAdhesionRMA.BeneficiareEnfants);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();

    }
}
```

I don't know how to handle that list from the controller nor the view with razor.

I would really appreciate some ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What part is not working, the view, the controller, everything?. The controller code you tried, is it the Get or Post method that was not working?

Comment: I tried the post method, but the controller isn't working, and i'm trying to pass the class which has a property of type List